# Python regex parsing

Tags: python, regex

I have an array of strings in python which each string in the array looking something like this:

```
<r n="Foo Bar" t="5" s="10" l="25"/>
```

I have been searching around for a while and the best thing I could find is attempting to modify a HTML hyperlink regex into something that will fit my needs.

But not really knowing much regex stuff I havent had anything work yet. This is what I have so far.

```
string = '<r n="Foo Bar" t="5" s="10" l="25"/>'
print re.split("<r\s+n=(?:\"(^\"]+)\").*?/>", string)
```

What would be the best way to extract the values of n, t, s, and l from that string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will get you most of the way there:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'(\w+)="(.*?)"', string)
[('n', 'Foo Bar'), ('t', '5'), ('s', '10'), ('l', '25')]
```

[re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) and [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) are complementary.

Every time your thought process begins with "I want each item that looks like X", then you should use `re.findall`. When it starts with "I want the data between and surrounding each X", use `re.split`.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> <r n="Foo Bar" t="5" s="10" l="25"/>
> ```

That source looks like XML, so the "the best way" would be to use an XML parsing module.. If it's not exactly XML, BeautifulSoup (or rather, the `BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup` module) may work best, as it's good at dealing with possibly-invalid XML (or things that "aren't *quite* XML"):

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulStoneSoup("""<r n="Foo Bar" t="5" s="10" l="25"/>""")

# grab the "r" element (You could also use soup.findAll("r") if there are multiple
>>> soup.find("r")
<r n="Foo Bar" t="5" s="10" l="25"></r>

# get a specific attribute
>>> soup.find("r")['n']
u'Foo Bar'
>>> soup.find("r")['t']
u'5'

# Get all attributes, or turn them into a regular dictionary
>>> soup.find("r").attrs
[(u'n', u'Foo Bar'), (u't', u'5'), (u's', u'10'), (u'l', u'25')]
>>> dict(soup.find("r").attrs)
{u's': u'10', u'l': u'25', u't': u'5', u'n': u'Foo Bar'}
```